# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a probability measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let Y be an non negative random variable
with $\mathbb{E}(Y) = 1$. For $A \in \mathcal{F}$
$$\mathbb{Q}(A) := \int_{A} Y(\omega)d \mathbb{P}(w)$$

*****a)** Prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$.***

so basically I have to prove that the expectation is a probability measure?

I have to show, that
$\mathbb{Q}(\phi)=0$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\Omega)=1$
so the first one is clear
$\mathbb{Q}(\Omega)= \int_{\Omega} Y(\omega)d \mathbb{P}(w)$, does $\mathbb{Q}(\Omega)=1$ follow from $\mathbb{E}(Y) = 1$ ? (because $\mathbb{Q}$ is exactly the definition of the expected value?).

for the remaining properties of a probability measure,
do I have to consider 1) simple functions, and 2) a sequence of functions? (to be able to use the MCT?), or is there something else? (could someone give me a hint on how to write this in a clean way?)

**b)**
**Let Z be another non-negative rv. Prove that
$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[Z] = \mathbb{E}[ZY]$**

so if $Z$ was the indicator function, it would be easy, but how can I consider other cases?

Comment: For $\mathbb{Q}(\Omega) = E(Y)$ and it is given to equal to 1 as what you said, the choice of the r.v. Y made it like that

Comment: What are the other two properties you need to verify?

Comment: @IrbidMath: I think I would also need to show the sigma additivity?

Comment: you need to show it is nonnegative and countable additive

Comment: For countable additivity use Monotone Convergence Theorem. Prove b)  first for simple functions $Z$ and then take limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part A: The only non-trivial part is showing countable additivity. To see this, let $(A_n)$ be a sequence of disjoint measurable sets and let $A$ denote their union. Defining the non-decreasing sequence of functions $f_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}1_{A_k}$ it follows by monotone convergence that
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}Q(A_k) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int Y f_n dP = \int \lim_n Y f_n dP = \int_A Y dP = Q(A)
\end{align}
as desired.

\Break

Part B: As you noted, it holds for indicators, thus also for simple functions. Let $(S_n)$ be a family of non-decreasing simple functions converging $P$-almost surely (thus the convergence is also true $Q$ almost surely) to $Z$. Using MCT we have that
\begin{align}
E(ZY) = E(\lim_n S_nY) = \lim_n E( S_nY) = \lim_n E^Q( S_n) =  E^Q(Z)
\end{align}
as desired. Note that $Y$ is actually known as the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $Q$ w.r.t. $P$.

Comment: Thank you very much